# list of exotic production functions?

Tags: production-function

Standard production functions are Cobb-Douglas, CES, Leontief.

The most exotic production function I have seen is the Ethier production function.

I am wondering whether there is a book/list of other exotic production functions. i.e. production functions with heterogeneous capital, integrals, etc.

I could not find it doing a google scholar search.

Answer (score 3):

[Belo (2010)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=890956) uses a production function 
$$
Y_{j,t} = \epsilon_{j,t} F^j(K_{j,t})
$$
where a competitive producer $j$ is allowed to choose the state-contingent productivity level $\epsilon_{j,t}$, subject to the constraint set
defined by the following analytically tractable CES aggregator:
$$
E_t\left[ \left( \frac{\epsilon_{j,t+1}}{\Theta_{j, t+1}}\right)^\alpha \right]^{1/\alpha} \leq 1.
$$
In Cochrane's  2016 essay, "Macro-Finance", Cochrane mentions this specification as a potentially important ingredient for understanding the interaction of macroeconomics and financial markets:

> The second ingredient, I think, is to enrich the production technology
>   so that consumer investors can shape the riskiness of the
>   technological opportunities they face. Belo (2010) and Jermann (2013)
>   have recently explored specifications of technology that allow such
>   choices.